# My Linux kernel module failed to request from system keyring

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, cryptography, kernel, kernel-module

I'm new to the development of kernel module. I want my module to perform a task like **signature verification**, so I add my own self-signed certificate path to `CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS` and compile to kernel. The key can be seen through `cat /proc/keys` like (the last entry):

```
040268c0 I------     1 perm 1f0b0000     0     0 keyring   .builtin_regdb_keys: 1
152aaaa3 I------     1 perm 1f030000     0     0 keyring   .id_resolver: empty
1eede733 I--Q---     1 perm 1f3f0000     0 65534 keyring   _uid_ses.0: 1
249059d2 I------     1 perm 1f030000     0     0 asymmetri sforshee: 00b28ddf47aef9cea7: X509.rsa []
299b6a42 I--Q---     2 perm 1f3f0000     0 65534 keyring   _uid.0: empty
3bce6f1c I------     1 perm 1f030000     0     0 keyring   .dns_resolver: empty
3d6c305b I------     1 perm 1f0b0000     0     0 keyring   .builtin_trusted_keys: 1
3d9c2543 I------     1 perm 1f030000     0     0 asymmetri <...>: <...>: <...>: X509.rsa 4c9c3ec4 []
```

Since this works fine, I want to **get this key in my kernel module code**. I have read some docs and used the following API to get key:

```c
struct key *request_key(const struct key_type *type,
                        const char *description,
                        const char *callout_string);
```

My code is like:

```c
struct key *key;
key = request_key(&key_type_asymmetric, "<...>: <...>: <...>", NULL);
```

In `<...>` is my personal information.

I have debug at other place and I believe I have passed a correct `description` string. But I always get a `ENOKEY`. Can anybody tells me if there is any mistake? Or there is a better way to get a key? Thx.

Also, I have tried other keys in the list, and I can only get the key with description `_uid_ses.0` and `_uid.0`.